# How to create a shell script that would create a copy of a file (selected by the user) and copy it to a directory (selected by the user) in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, file-copy, user-input

How to solve this task?

> To create a copy of a file.
>
> - The file should be in your current directory (the name of the file to be given by the user)
> - The destination directory name to be given by the user.

This is how far I've got:

```
echo "Enter the name of the file:"
read filename 
cp -r /home/$FILE ;;
```

Just to add more info, this is what the full exercise is based on:

The script should offer a menu with the following options:

```
1. To create a backup copy of a script file.
```

> The name of the backup copy should have backup after the name of the script 
>        and be date stamped e.g. work3Script_backup_10_11_2015.
>
> It should be saved to your home directory using the Environment Variable 
>         for your home directory.
>
> The script should error check that the file exists and is a normal file.  If 
>       this is not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the 
>       filename until a valid filename is entered

```
2. To create a date stamped log file called e.g. log_file_10_11_2015   
   containing 

 >  A list of who is logged into the system

 >  The disk usage and

 >  Your currently running processes. 

 >  The file should be saved to an existing directory called log_dir which 
   should 
   be situated off your home directory


3. To create a copy of a file.
```

> The file should be in your current directory (the name of the file to be 
>         given by the user)
>
> The destination directory name to be given by the user.
>
> The script should error check that the file exists and is a normal file.      If this is not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the filename until a valid filename is entered.
>
> The script should check that the destination directory exists.  If this is 
>       not the case then the script should allow the user to re-enter the 
>       destination directory until a valid directory is entered.

Here is the menu I created:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
echo "=============================="
echo            "Menu"
echo "=============================="
echo "Option 1 Backing up files: "
echo "Option 2 Date stamped log file: "
echo "Option 3 Create a copy of a file: "
echo "Option 4 Moving a file to place giving by the user: "
echo "Enter q to quit the menu: "
echo -e "\n"
echo -e "Enter your option: \c"
read answer
case "$answer" in

1) while true ; do
   echo "Enter the file name:"
   read filename
   if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
       echo "The file exists."
       break
   else
       echo "File doesn't exist."
   fi
done

FILE=$(date +"outcome3_backup_%d_%m_%y.sh")
touch /home/robert/$FILE ;;


2)FILE=$(date +"log_file_%d_%m_%y.txt")
  touch /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE

  echo "Users online: " > /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE
  (users) >> /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE


  echo "Running proccesses:" >> /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE
  ps -a >> /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE


  echo "Available disk space:" >> /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE
  df --total -h|head -n 1 >> /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE
  df --total -h|tail -n 1 >> /home/robert/log_dir/$FILE ;;


3) ;;


q) exit ;;

esac
done
```

Comment: I've used the `{}` button to format your code as `code`. I've also quoted your homework question to make it stand out more clearly

Comment: So... if you repeat the first two lines, adjusting as necessary, you can ask the user for the destination directory name. You can then use https://shellcheck.net/ to pick up any "more obvious" errors in the code. Don't forget to make the very first line of code `#!/bin/bash` to declare that this is a `bash` shell script.

Comment: "Given by the user" doesn't necessarily mean "read in interactively", it could just mean "given as command line arguments" (in fact, reading interactively would make the script awkward to use). Your script then only has to make sure that the arguments are valid (the first, `$1`, is the pathname of a file, the second, `$2`, is the pathname of a directory), and then call `cp "$1" "$2"`. Without the validation of the arguments, the whole script becomes, literally, `cp "$1" "$2"` (plus the `#!`-line).

Comment: Why do you use only one prompt if the task requires two prompts? Also, until now,  two different variable names refer to the same thing? I think you are on the right track,  just clear your mind.

Comment: @Kusalananda looks like a school exercise to sanitize user input.

Comment: @The OP only has one input. Hopefully because the are doing one thing at a time. When it works they will add the next feature. Writing a whole program, full of bugs, then removing all the bugs, is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Sorva, J. (2018) Misconceptions and the beginner programmer. In: Barendsen, E., Schulte, S., Sentance, S. (eds.) Computer science education: perspectives on teaching and learning in school. London, Bloosmbury, pp. 171-188. -- M18: Programs are interpreted more or less like sentences in natural conversation. The computer or programming environment is, for practical purposes, able to deduce the intention of the programmer. It may for instance, fill in the ‘obvious’ missing information without being taught. -- Variable name differ in first example, computer sees these as completely different.

Comment: indent code to make it readable (the code at the end).

Answer (score 0):

In Sorva, J. (2018) Misconceptions and the beginner programmer. In: Barendsen, E., Schulte, S., Sentance, S. (eds.) Computer science education: perspectives on teaching and learning in school. London, Bloosmbury, pp. 171-188. There is a lisp of popular misconceptions on how computers interpret computer programs

> M18: Programs are interpreted more or less like sentences in natural conversation. The computer or programming environment is, for practical purposes, able to deduce the intention of the programmer. It may for instance, fill in the ‘obvious’ missing information without being taught.

I.E. Variable name differs in your first example. The computer sees these as completely different.

```
echo "Enter the name of the file:"
read filename 
cp -r /home/$FILE
```

`FILE` is not the same as `filename`: differs in case and spelling.

---

Side note: don't use all caps in variable names. And pass you script through `shellcheck`, to find errors.

## shellcheck

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the name of the file:"
read filename
cp -r /home/$FILE' | shellcheck /dev/stdin
```

Returns

```
In /dev/stdin line 3:
read filename
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.
     ^-- SC2034: filename appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).


In /dev/stdin line 4:
cp -r /home/$FILE
^-- SC2225: This cp has no destination. Check the arguments.
            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```